# AsyncTask onPostExecute not doing everything it should

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have an problem here, the onPostExecute() method isn't doing everything it should.

As you can see in my onPostExecute, an Boolean value decides what happens.
But what happens is, if you get b through log you don't see anything, the code that executes is the one for b = true

The dialog is showed en says it was succesfull but the preferences won't get updated, what am I doing wrong here?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
    publishProgress(100);
    dialog.dismiss();
    if (b) {
        e.putInt(Constants.pref_updateweek, cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
        e.commit();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alert.setTitle("Succes");
        alert.setMessage("Alles is bijgewerkt");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);

        alert.show();
        act.commUI();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Er is een fout opgetreden.");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);

        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: publishProgress(100); should be in doInBackground(). AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); Can move this before if

Comment: Could you put the code of the whole AsynTask? Look at the boolean that the e.commit() returns (returns true if the new values were successfully written to persistent storage). It can be a problem of your sharedpreferences initialization<->context

Comment: source available on this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pkdrRGFV) till 19:17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found my problem, feel really stupid now

```
e.putInt(Constants.pref_updateweek, cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
e.commit();
```

In the first version of my app I forgot the `e.commit()`, and in an update I fixed it.

In another class I have the same AsyncTask but with a little different things, so I copied the old code to that class (without the `e.commit()`) so the problem was not in the code in my question but in very similair code in another class, but thanks for the suggestions!